# How to set Android button inside dialog that was called from listview?

Tags: android, button, dialog

I have code that goes like this:

```
public class Screening extends ListActivity implements OnClickListener{
...
Button screeningOK, set, cancel;
...
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) 
{
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    int listPosition = position; 

    switch(listPosition){
    case _AGESELECTION:
        Dialog d = new Dialog(Screening.this);
        d.setTitle(R.string.ageselector_title);
        set = (Button)d.findViewById(R.id.bSet);
        cancel = (Button)d.findViewById(R.id.bCancel);
        //set.setOnClickListener(this);



        cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });
        d.setContentView(R.layout.agedialog);
        d.show();

    break;
```

So short explanation, I have a list that opens dialog.
Dialog has NumberPicker, set and cancel buttons.

Now, on Set, I'd like to save NumPicker value, and cancel to cancel dialog. (finish(); will most likely finish activity but that's not the issue, issue is that no matter if I set new on click listener like:

```
set.setOnClickListener(this);
```

or

```
cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
        }
    });
```

It crashes my app with Null pointer exception.

There is onClick function within main class because original activity consists of list, radio buttons and Save Button.

I assume something with the fact that I already have onClickListener is giving me hard time here, but can't figure out what.

Please Advise.

tnx.

Comment: use DialogInterface.OnClickListener

Comment: @Satya - But where? within case selection, or within onClick method. Tnx